# Find duplicate rows escaping first column

Tags: bash

I have a tsv file with data from some event participants. Here is a small snippet from it:

```
...
sub-09          37   F    19780726   20160328    20160329
sub-10          38   F    19780208   20160406    20160407
sub-11          39   M    19770511   20160704    20160705
...
sub-42          37   F    19780726   20160328    20160329
...
```

Note that sub-09 and sub-42 are duplicates.

In BASH, how can I find duplicate lines but ignoring the first (or in general any other) column?
I've seen similar threads, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095523/script-to-find-duplicates-in-a-csv-file#4098249), but I couldn't find an answer that fits. Ideally I would get both occurrences of all duplicates, as in:

Expected output:

```
sub-09          37   F    19780726   20160328    20160329
sub-42          37   F    19780726   20160328    20160329
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava Thx. Just added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uniq -d` to show duplicates. Use its `-f` option to skip fields. As `uniq` needs the input sorted, first sort ignoring the first column:

```
sort -nk2 file | uniq -f1 -d
```

Use `-D` instead of `-d` if you want all the duplicates.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk based solution that avoids sorting the file (which can be pretty expensive for a large file):

```
awk '{
   p = $1
   $1 = ""
   freq[$0]++
   col1[$0,freq[$0]] = p
} 
END {
   for (i in freq)
      for (j=1; freq[i]>1 && j<=freq[i]; j++)
         print col1[i,j] i
 }' file

sub-09 37 F 19780726 20160328 20160329
sub-42 37 F 19780726 20160328 20160329
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{$1="";a[$0]++;next}{s=$0;$1="";if(a[$0]>=2) print s}' file file
```

Comment: Please add an explication as to how your code solves the issue.