# How to delete duplicates from one specific column in python with 20 milion rows

Tags: python, csv, bigdata

I would like to delete duplicates from one large csv. I have this csv format of data

```
client_id;gender;age;profese;addr_cntry;NAZOKRESU;prijem_AVG_6M_pasmo;cont_id;main_prod_id;bal_actl_am_pasmo
388713248;F;80;důchodce;CZ;Czech;;5715125;39775;
27953927;M;28;Dělník;CZ;Opavia;22;4427292;39075;
```

**I need delete all duplicates from client_id.**
I can not handle this big file in python with Pandas. I tried dask, but same result. Just infinity time of waiting and nothing really happend.

Here is my last version of code

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import chardet
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

with open('bigData.csv', 'rb') as f:
    result = chardet.detect(f.read())

df = dd.read_csv('bigData.csv', encoding=result['encoding'], sep=';')

total_rows = df.shape[0].compute()

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['client_id'], keep=False, Inplace=True)

df.to_csv('bigData.csv', sep=';', index=False)

total_duplicates = total_rows - df.shape[0].compute()

print(f'Was deleted {total_duplicates} duplicated rows.')
```

I tried it with progress bar and nothing really happened. Thanks for help!

Comment: I have solved duplicate-removal with AWK a few times, it works well also with very large files. A python way to solve the problem is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452832/remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-large-file-in-python).

Comment: Thanks for comment, AWS is out of my scope. I am windows user, but thanks for trying!

Comment: I am a Windows user too. AWK is [available for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnu-awk-for-windows/) and works 99% like on Linux / Mac.  Have you tried the linked suggestion in the other question, using SQLite and key index ?

Comment: The solution I linked to using SQLite is **significantly** slower, so not ideal for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able get away with a very simple Python program that stores every new ID it sees in a dict, and skips writing a subsequent row if it finds that row's ID already in the dict.  It  should require about 2GB of RAM.

```py
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("input.csv", newline=""))
writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w", newline=""))

writer.writerow(next(reader))  # transfer header, if you have one

ids = {}
for row in reader:
    if row[0] not in ids:
        writer.writerow(row)
        ids[row[0]] = None  # add ID to "list" of already written IDs
```

This approach:

- Uses a dict, `ids`, to hold all IDs the program has already encountered and written; dicts can do really fast lookups/checks for its keys (your IDs).
- Keeps the original ordering of the rows.

I mocked up a CSV w/20M rows (with randomly generated IDs between 0 and 20M), that looks something like this:

```
| id       | i |
|----------|---|
| 2266768  | 0 |
| 15245359 | 1 |
| 16304974 | 2 |
| 4801643  | 3 |
| 9612409  | 4 |
| 17659151 | 5 |
| 15824934 | 6 |
| 4101873  | 7 |
| 12282127 | 8 |
| 5172219  | 9 |
```

I ran it through that program and ended up with 12.6M rows.  On my Macbook Air M1 (dual-channel SSD) that took 14 seconds and consumed 1.5GB of RAM.  The RAM is needed to hold all the previously seen IDs.

Also, I see you reading the entire file first to detect the character encoding:

- Have you tried running `chardetect` from the command line, `chardetect input.csv`, and just hard-coding the value returned?
- Have you experimented with reading a much smaller portion of the file and seeing what results and confidence you get?

  ```py
  with open("input.csv", "rb") as f:
      input_enc = chardet.detect(f.read(1024 * 64))  # only read first 64K

  print(input_enc)  # {'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
  ```

Comment: Since you already have the source file: out of interest, could you do a performance test (RAM/ time) with the SQLite (external file) solution, and possibly doing it in AWK ?  I can do it myself, but comparing from same source would make sense.

Comment: Hi @MyICQ, I don't know AWK, so I couldn't do a fair comparison. You seem to favor AWK, will you take my answer and write your best AWK script and compare? I'm personally curious how their performance compares, in general, but I would never consider AWK for a general-purpose CSV parser. [Here's the small Python script](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/da51b614acc7f8e97b249d1f47302900#file-gen-20m-random-ids-py) I used to generate the 20M random IDs. Thanks!

Comment: Not trying to be in absolut favor of AWK, just curious about which way (python/dict,  python/SQLite, AWK, ... ) is faster. I will update later.

Answer (score 1):

Same task using AWK. This is not what op asked, just to complete comment above.  Do not accept as answer.

```
BEGIN{
  FS=","   # set field separator to comma
}
!seen[$2]++ {    # is field 2 not seen before ? 
    print $0
}
```

Sample data:

```
RowNum,ID
1,5220607
2,8632078
3,8323076
..
```

Run as `c:\>awk -f script.awk  input.csv  > uniquevalues.csv`

This outputs about 12 mio rows, and consumes 1,8GB memory in about 18 seconds (i7 Windows).

The python script from @zach-young above on same computer and file was about 35 seconds, but less memory.